# How to query Azure Table via Python for Timestamp correctly?

Tags: python, azure

I want to have the same results for running query using Python as in Azure portal

Inside Azure Cosmos Table I have entity UserOpinion with 2 rows having Timestamps:
Mon, 21 Oct 2019 10:56:04 GMT ; 
Mon, 21 Oct 2019 11:32:49 GMT

Query Timestamp ge datetime'2019-10-16T18:11:36.378Z'
inside Azure portal returns 2 rows as result.

```py
table_service = TableService(endpoint_suffix="table.cosmos.azure.com", connection_string=connection_string) 
objects = table_service.query_entities("UserOpinion", filter = "Timestamp ge datetime'2019-10-16T18:11:36.378Z'" )
```

The list of objects returned from Python is empty, but it doesn't throw any format exception

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing you comparison of datetime to something like below:

```
filter = "Timestamp gt datetime'" + '2019-10-16T18:11:36.378Z'+ "'"
```

Also you can try something liek below too:

```
table_service.query_entities('DeviceData', "Timestamp gt datetime'2016-05-01T00:00:00.000Z'")
```

Additional reference:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/202

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately get same results, to be precise it is azure.storage.common.models.ListGenerator object which gives len([o for o in objects]) equal to 0

Comment: I can confirm the same result. It is buggy.